# Can't get access token for profiles Auth0

Tags: angular, auth0

When I log in with Auth0 credentials and go to profile page I get the following error:

> Access Token must exist to fetch profile

I can see the access token when logging in in the URL, however it must not be saving. Hopefully someone can help. Following tutorial from Auth0 website just stuck on this. Any ideas would be great. Feel free to ask for more information if you need it.

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

private _idToken: string;
private _accessToken: string;
private expiresAt: number;

auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
clientID: 'my id,
domain: 'my domain',
responseType: 'token id_token',
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:',
scope: 'openid profile'
});
map: any;
userProfile: any;


constructor(public router: Router) {
this._idToken = '';
this._accessToken = '';
  this.expiresAt = 0;
}

public login(): void {
sessionStorage.url = window.location.href;
this.auth0.authorize();
}

get accessToken(): string {
    return this._accessToken;
    }

 get idToken(): string {
 return this._idToken;
 }


 public getProfile(cb): void {
 if (!this._accessToken) {
  throw new Error('Access Token must exist to fetch profile');
 }

 const self = this;
 this.auth0.client.userInfo(this._accessToken, (err, profile) => {
  if (profile) {
    self.userProfile = profile;
  }
   cb(err, profile);
  });
}

    public handleAuthentication(): void {
  this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    window.location.hash = '';
    this.setSession(authResult);
   // this.router.navigate(['/']);
  } else if (err) {
   // this.router.navigate(['/']);
    console.log(err);
  }
});
}

 private setSession(authResult): void {
  // Set the time that the Access Token will expire at
 const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new 
 Date().getTime());
 localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
 localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
 localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
 }


 public logout(): void {
// Remove tokens and expiry time from localStorage
 localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
 localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
 localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
// Go back to the home route
 this.router.navigate(['/']);
 }

 public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  // Check whether the current time is past the
  // Access Token's expiry time
  const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
  return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }

  public renewTokens(): void {
 this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    this.setSession(authResult);
  } else if (err) {
    alert(`Could not get a new token (${err.error}: 
  ${err.error_description}).`);
    this.logout();
  }
});
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which tutorial you followed but the current recommendation by Auth0 in their Angular Quickstart is not saving the Access Token in LocalStorage. It is only keeping it in memory for security reasons.

Your `getProfile` function will fail on the first line because `this._accessToken` is never set to the actual token you received in `handleAuthentication` function.

You can fix that by adding this line to the `setSession` function:

```
this._accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
```

I recommend to further improve this by not storing the Token(s) in the Browser's Local Storage, you can follow the best practices explained in the official Docs [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login#finish-the-service).